# GitLab reconfigure exists on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, gitlab, raspbian

Just did a fresh install of **GitLib** on a raspberry pi *(original)* running Raspbian.

```
wget https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-packages/raspberry-pi/gitlab_7.9.0-omnibus.pi-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i gitlab_7.9.0-omnibus.pi-1_armhf.deb
```

When I try and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` it runs for maybe 5 seconds, then just exists with status code `1`. No error message or output.

Any ideas?